# Before/after slider, can't get it to work on website

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

So I'm trying to insert a code for this before/after slider into the HTML widget of elementor,
But it's not loading the code properly. How can i adjust it to make it work?
Is the .container an issue because it gets overwritten by the theme/elementor?
I'm just not sure what exactly I have to modify.
The slider should be vertical and is horizontal and the image only shows like the the top 3 pixels of it, the rest is completely white.

```js
$("#slider").on("input change", (e) => {
  const sliderPos = e.target.value;
  // Update the width of the foreground image
  $('.foreground-img').css('width', `${sliderPos}%`)
  // Update the position of the slider button
  $('.slider-button').css('left', `calc(${sliderPos}% - 18px)`)
});
```

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 900px;
  height: 600px;
  border: 2px solid white;
}

.container .img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-size: 900px 100%;
}

.container .img.background-img {
  background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/s08MkXC.jpg');
}

.container .img.foreground-img {
  background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/PfIWek4.jpg');
  width: 50%;
}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(242, 242, 242, 0.3);
  outline: none;
  margin: 0;
  transition: all .2s;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.slider:hover {
  background: rgba(242, 242, 242, .1);
}

.slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  width: 6px;
  height: 600px;
  background: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.slider-button {
  --size: 30px;
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: var(--size);
  height: var(--size);
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: white;
  left: calc(50% - 18px);
  top: calc(50% - 18px);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.slider-button:after {
  content: '';
  padding: 3px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: solid #5D5D5D;
  border-width: 0 2px 2px 0;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.slider-button:before {
  content: '';
  padding: 3px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: solid #5D5D5D;
  border-width: 0 2px 2px 0;
  transform: rotate(135deg);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class='container'>
    <div class='img background-img'></div>
    <div class='img foreground-img'></div>
    <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" class="slider" name='slider' id="slider">
    <div class='slider-button'></div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js">
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Your code works when put into a snippet. Is it only nonfunctional in your Elementor widget? What do you see when you inspect it in your website using your browser devtools?